# function to get dummies from vector

Tags: r, function

I made a simple function that returns a vector of 1 or 0 depending on whether the value at the ith position is greater or smaller than the average of the vecor. That works fine.

So, I attemped to build a similar function to return 1 in the cases where the value at i is greater than 75% of the distribution. However, I get a "object x not found" error when I try to run this code:

```
75dummy <- function(x)
{
  a <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] > (quantile(x, probs=0.75))) {a[i]<-1} else {a[i] <- 0}
  } 
  a
}
```

Running the same function with mean(x) substituted in for the quantile expression works. Similarly the quantile form works by itself using any vector.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok nevermind, I changed the name of the function removing the 75 and it seems to work. Didn't know naming function including numbers would cause them not to work?

Comment: I did but it didn't specify what kind of error, just "Object x not found". Didn't know I wasn't supposed to do that. Just started using R a couple of weeks ago:)

Comment: don't know "r" but maybe it's because it's start by a number, not because it includes one.

Comment: Function names can *include* numbers, they just can't start with them; e.g. `dummy75` would be fine.

Comment: Also, check out the `cut` function which I believe does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, this function did not work because of its naming. There are rules that govern the naming of R objects

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the reserved words.

A good way to check whether your name is valid or not is to use `make.names` which will automatically resolve any invalid syntax or characters:

```
> make.names("75dummy")
[1] "X75dummy"
```

The function will also resolve any reserved R words:

```
> make.names(c("if", "else", "repeat", "function", Inf, NA, NULL, TRUE))
[1] "if."       "else."     "repeat."   "function." "Inf."      "NA."       "TRUE."
```

Ref: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html

Answer (score 0):

This will store the vector and result(0,1) in a data.frame

```
set.seed(321)
x <- rnorm(10)
data.frame(x, lvl = as.numeric(x >= quantile(x, .75)))

            x lvl
1   1.7049032   1
2  -0.7120386   0
3  -0.2779849   0
4  -0.1196490   0
5  -0.1239606   0
6   0.2681838   0
7   0.7268415   1
8   0.2331354   0
9   0.3391139   1
10 -0.5519147   0
```

Or to make a function to return a vector from a vector

```
myfn <- function(y, prob=.75) as.numeric(y >= quantile(x, prob))
myfn(x)
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: that's definitely quicker, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad this was helpful